# Python string comparison not working as expected

Tags: python, string, comparison

I'm using python 2.7 and trying to simply take an input from a person (via raw_input) and then output a string depending on what was typed into the input, but the behavior I am getting is that the first logic test in my "if" statement always executes, no matter what I type.

Any ideas why this is not working?

```
another_card = raw_input("Another card: (Y or N) ")

print "The value of another_card is: " + another_card 

if another_card == "Y" or "y":
    print "Good on you"
elif another_card == "N" or "n":
    print "Wimp. Game over."
else:
    print "What the hell did you type?"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `if another_card == "Y" or another_card == "y":`

Comment: Also you'll simplify your life with ```if another_card.lower() == "y":...```

Comment: @AvinashRaj In these situations I prefer `if another_card in ['Y', 'y']:` as it is a bit shorter on the eye.

Comment: @DeepSpace let's educate op to how to use `or` operator (aka keyword).

Comment: Thanks. I see that it has to be two discreet comparison operations now, but do you know why it was passing the first logic test originally?